# Isabelle: adjusting lemma to form required for `rule` method

Tags: isabelle

I define an inductive relation called `step_g`. Here is one of the inference rules:

```
G_No_Op:
  "∀j ∈ the (T i). ¬ (eval_bool p (the (γ ⇩t⇩s j)))
  ⟹ step_g a i T (γ, (Barrier, p)) (Some γ)"
```

I want to invoke this rule in a proof, so I type

```
apply (rule step_g.G_No_Op)
```

but the rule cannot be applied, because its conclusion must be of a particular form already (the two γ's must match). So I adapt the rule like so:

```
lemma G_No_Op_helper:
  "⟦ ∀j ∈ the (T i). ¬ (eval_bool p (the (γ ⇩t⇩s j))) ; γ = γ' ⟧
  ⟹ step_g a i T (γ, (Barrier, p)) (Some γ')"
by (simp add: step_g.G_No_Op)
```

Now, when I invoke `rule G_No_Op_helper`, the requirement that "the two γ's must match" becomes a subgoal to be proven.

The transformation of `G_No_Op` into `G_No_Op_helper` looks rather mechanical. My question is: is there a way to make Isabelle do this automatically?

---

**Edit.** I came up with a "minimal working example". In the following, lemma `A` is equivalent to `A2`, but `rule A` doesn't help to prove the theorem, only `rule A2` works.

```
consts foo :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat ⇒ bool"

lemma A: "x < y ⟹ foo y x x"
sorry

lemma A2: "⟦ x < y ; x = z ⟧ ⟹ foo y x z"
sorry

theorem "foo y x z"
apply (rule A)
```

Comment: Intersting; I have had similar issues like this before. A „Match this rule, dammit, and give me all failed unifications as subgoals!“ might be handy from time to time.

Comment: I suspect that could be problematic because there might be many different possibilities to add equations to make something unifiable. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, nothing exists to automate these things. One could probably implement this as an attribute, i.e.

```
thm A[generalised x]
```

to obtain something like A2. The attribute would replace every occurence of the variable it is given (i.e. `x` here) but the first  in the conclusion of the theorem with a fresh variable `x'` and add the premise `x' = x` to the theorem.

This shouldn't be very hard to implement for someone more skilled in Isabelle/ML than me – maybe some of the advanced Isabelle/ML hackers who read this could comment on the idea.

Answer (score 2):

There is a well-known principle "proof-by-definition", i.e. you write your initial specifications in a way such the the resulting rules are easy to apply.  This might occasionally look unexpected to informal readers, but is normal for formalists.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems and wrote a method named fuzzy_rule, which can be used like this:

```
theorem "foo y x z"
  apply (fuzzy_rule A)
  subgoal "x < y" 
    sorry
  subgoal "x = z"
    sorry
```

The code is available at https://github.com/peterzeller/isabelle_fuzzy_rule